# Eclipse doesn't start but can restart

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I try to use Eclipse (in Windows 11) for working with Wolfram Workbench (Eclipse-based IDE for the Wolfram Language)
But I face with very strange situation. After installing Eclipse can be started, it is possible to install Wolfram Workbench plugin in it and adjust some parameters. If I restart application (File>Restart), Eclipse restarts as needed and any number of times. But if I exit application, the run is impossible. After starting a splash window appears for a moment, but application immediately cancels.
I tried install/uninstall Eclipse several times, the result is the same. I utterly confused by this.

I expect a normal start of Eclipse

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a  message. [Edit] your question to show us the extra detail.

Comment: Very, very strange performance. Today I reinstalled Eclipse, but .log file contain yesterday's info: !SESSION 2024-01-18 20:57:15.930
No session on 2024-01-19

Comment: Eclipse never clears the log so old entries persist. The log is only written went there is something to report.